# How to make event available for dynamically added html jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I am doing some process that is running fine for first time loaded content using  -

```
$("#daily-table").find("td.user-slot").mousedown(function (e) {
   Some Process 
}
```

But its not working for dynamically added html, in 'daily-table' tag. Here is the code that i am trying for Dynamically added html  -

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "#daily-table > td.user-slot" , function(e) { 
   Some Process 
}
```

Here is the HTML structure  -

```
<table id="daily-table" class="slotsdata">
<tbody>
    <tr class="tr-scheduled startTimeRow odd" >
        <td class="timetitle time-slot"><span>10:00 AM</span></td>
        <td class="user-slot" ><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="tx-white tx-11 tx-medium">Anchor1</a></td>
        <td class="user-slot" ><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="tx-white tx-11 tx-medium">Anchor2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-scheduled startTimeRow odd" >
        <td class="timetitle time-slot"><span>11:00 AM</span></td>
        <td class="user-slot" ><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="tx-white tx-11 tx-medium">Anchor3</a></td>
        <td class="user-slot" ><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="tx-white tx-11 tx-medium">Anchor4</a></td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
```

Plz help me to solve this ...
Thanks

Comment: Is your selector correct? Can you share workable code?

Comment: Yes, selector is correct,

Comment: Could you  share your html?

Comment: Plz check question, I have added HTML in that

Comment: I think there should be `.time-slot` in jquery. You are using `.user-slot`.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I need to get data of only <td> with class -  user-slot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `td.user-slot` element is not an immediate descendant of `#daily-table`, so don't use the [Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "#daily-table td.user-slot" , function(e) {
    /* 'this' refers to the <td> DOM element */

    const $td = $(this);
    /* $td is now a jQuery collection containing the DOM element */
});
```

Comment: Thx George, It works for me. , Can you plz let me know how to make it dynamic, `$("#daily-table").find("td.user-slot").bind("selectstart", function () {
  return false;
});`

Comment: You could add e.target inside the function to make dynamic. You could read about event bubbling and capturing/delegation, it about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".time-slot").function(e) { 
   //Some Process 
};
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this syntax is invalid, that's not how `on` works.